# swift - there is a cell in the empty tableview

Tags: swift, core-data, tableview

I have several tableviews, one of them uses coredata and others get data from a json api. In my tableview which gets data from coredata, when I launch the app there is a cell, but my coredata is empty. Cell disappears when I reload the table. 
How am I going to remove that cell?

Comment: Parts of your code could be very useful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply add code to erase all cells if your core data is empty. You do this in the ViewWillAppear(), if your core data object is empty then return 0 at your numberOfRows in table.

You could also add a self update function (by NSNotifications) which reads the current amount of data (count) and then do a reloadData() call.

These are only suggestions... we don't really know how your code looks like to be able to suggest a better answer.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the following line of code in viewDidLoad() or viewWillAppear() to clear unwanted cells from UITableview.

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
```

If Table is initially empty then there will be no cell to display.